# How many examples like as this sum of distinct primes $2+3=5$ being $30$ a primorial, are there?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, primorial

Since $2+3=5$ I know a simle example of a triple of coprime integers $(a,b,c)$, 
such that $$a+b=c,$$
being each summand a product of distinct primes $a=2$, $b=3$ and $c=5$, and their product is a primorial $$abc=2\cdot3\cdot 5.$$ It is the primorial or order $3$, that is the positive integer $30$.

I believe that the following problem should be in the literaute but I've curiosity about its solution

> **Question.** What about the triples of (coprime) integers $(a,b,c)$ being solutions of the equation $$\underbrace{\text{product of distinct primes}}_{a}+\underbrace{\text{product of distinct primes}}_{b}=\underbrace{\text{product of distinct primes}}_{c}$$ that satisfy the condition $$abc=\text{a primorial}?$$ What I am asking is if it is known that there exists a $K$ such that $\forall k\geq K$ there are no solution of our previous problem, o well in other case there are infinitely many solutions. **Many thanks.**

My belief is that should be few solutions. If this problem was in the literature refer the literature as an answer, and I try find the article.

**Edit:** I didn't know such sequence ,and I didn't calculate terms of such. Many thanks @RobertIsrael for your reference to OEIS, I add here thus the name of the author of the sequence Naohiro Nomoto (Sep 10 2000), and more terms were added by Carlos Rivera.

Comment: so then the question is if there is only finite solutions to a+b=c such that a,b and c are squarefree pairwise coprime integers such that abc is a primorial?

Comment: Many thanks @TacNayn for your words, since my english is bad. One can read my question also as: What primorials $N$ can you represent as a sum $a+b=c$ with $abc=N$? I am interested only in how many of those can you represent, if these are a finite number, or well you can show that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Note that you would not require that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are coprime since that's implied by the fact that $abc$ is primorial. In fact they must be pairwise coprime - otherwise $abc$ would be divisible by a square which a primorial can't.

Comment: You are right @skyking . Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For order $3$: $2+3=5$.

For order $4$: $3 + 7 = 10$.

For order $5$: $2 + 33 = 35$.

For order $6$: $13 + 42 = 55$.

For order $7$: $11 + 210 = 221$.

For order $8$: $57 + 385 = 442$.

For order $9$: $119 + 1311 = 1430$.

For order $10$: $1495 + 1463 = 2958$.

For order $11$: $374 + 22971 = 23345$.

For order $13$: $1235 + 495726 = 496961$.

EDIT: See [OEIS sequence A057035](https://oeis.org/A057035).

Comment: how did you find these? Brute force or some heuristics trying special combinations?

Comment: A rather brutish search.